# Should I use uuid() to provide id on the fly inside a React component

Tags: reactjs, components, key, render

It is well known that we should not use the index of an array as React component key for performance issue, as modifying it would re-render too many component for no reasons.

Cf. https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

So I was thinking, why not use a UUID when mapping:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function ListItem(props) {
  return <li key={props.id}>{props.value}</li>;
}

function MyList(props) {
  const listItems = props.items.map(item =>
    <ListItem key={uuidv4()} value={item.value} />
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

const items = [{ value: 'item 1' }, { value: 'item 2' }, { value: 'item 3' }];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyList items={items} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But then I am thinking that it's the same issue, because each time the MyList component will rerender, it will regenerate a new key for each item, and then there is no gain in this technique.

Hence the recommendation from the doc:
"When that’s not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. The key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique."
as a hash will be the same id each time, provided that we don't add salt.

Am I having a correct understanding of the issue at end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You must generate your keys based on your data.](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys) Each time you call `uuidv4()` it will generate a new, random value, which will not reconcile with the previous render.

Your quote is omitting an important remark from earlier:

> "When that’s not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. The key only has to be unique **[and stable]** among its siblings, not globally unique."

From beta docs:

> Similarly, do not generate keys on the fly, e.g. with key={Math.random()} **(Same goes for generated uuids)**. This will cause keys to never match up between renders, leading to all your components and DOM being recreated every time. Not only is this slow, but it will also lose any user input inside the list items. Instead, use a stable ID based on the data.